# SSIS Delete files from folder based on a selection from SQL Database

Tags: ssis, selection, delete-file

I have an issue regarding a deletion of files based on a selection.
So, I have an SQL table in which there is a column with the file name.
What I have to do is take the file name from there and delete the physical file with that name from a specified path.

What I have tried is to execute an sql task with the selection of full file paths (including file names) which need to be deleted and store them in an object variable and then try to do a ForEach Loop Container with a 'from variable enumerator' to take those results and delete the files using a file system task, but I don't think that's the right approach.
The execution of the package ends in success, but it ends at the ForEach Loop Container without reaching (executing) the file system task, so the files are not being deleted.

Select statement (also added the full path of the file as a column in order for the file system task to know where the physical file is stored) :

```
select file_full_path from t1
where flag = 'YES'
```

Do you guys know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set the loop to `Foreach ADO Enumerator` , so your process would be:

1: SQL Task - map file_full_path to an object variable, say 'filesdel'

[image]

2: Foreach Loop set to Foreach ADO Enumerator

[image]

3: Map the the the for loop items to a string variable, say 'filename':

[image]

4: Use the string variable in the File System Task

[image]

Comment: You beautiful person! This solution has worked like a charm. Thank you. Hope it helps others too.

Comment: @Jayvee, I get an error with this, 'variable used as a source or destination and is empty'.  I have just an empty variable I'm mapping to.  How does the object variable get mapped to the string variable?